Output of JointGroupVelocityControllers on PR2 robot_mechanism_controllers
I am on my way to understand the behavior of the JointGroupVelocityControllers used on PR2 robot mechanism controller. When using this controller to execute the desired joint velocity for a reactive bi-manual coordination task, I didn't get the velocity I expected on three first joints.
From the graph below for one arm joint velocities (blue is desired joint vel, red is actual one), my initial guess for the cause of this issue is the effort safety limit used after the PID layer of the controller as the observed change on desired velocity in joint 0 and joint 1 seems to have a huge acceleration.

I have checked online and know that JointVelocityController takes velocity command, then feed into a PID controller to specify the effort for the joint, then this is where the safety limit kicked in (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController). I am not sure if JointGroupVelocityControllers is working the same way. If the controller I am using work the same way, I can think of having an optimization filter to minimize the hug acceleration that lead to the effort on each joint exceed the limit of [-30Nm, 30Nm].
Thank you in advance.
